# Google dictionary as my database

Tags: php

Can I use Google dictionary as my database for the application developed in Php ? I want to create an application which will pop up meaning of each word,displayed in output window. So I thought that it will be useful if I use Google dictionary as my database,from there I can fetch meaning of each word.

I don't know whether my question is meaningful. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think Google will give you there dictionary

Comment: maybe you mean its API? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 1):

There was an unofficial `Google Dictionary API`, but google requested it to be closed down (if i remember right), so my guess is that scraping the Google dictionary site or access their undocumented `API` would not be *totally okay*.

There is a issue at [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=16) (more like a request for an `API`), first dated to may 2008 and latest post from Mars 2014.

You could maybe check out [glosbe](http://glosbe.com/a-api), and see if their `API` meets your requirements.